# How to open a file in the last closed position in VI

Tags: vim, vi

I want to open a file which is closed in line xxx. So I can easily continue editing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup an autocommand that executes when you open a file. If you add this to your .vimrc, that will do it.

```
au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g`\"" | endif
```

See `:help last-position-jump`; this line is pulled straight from there.

Comment: Most vi(m) I know of already do this. They propably have that setting in the global vimrc. Is there any reason to disable that feature?

Comment: According to [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_cursor_to_file_position_in_previous_editing_session), this method doesn't work for one-line files. The link contains another method which does (though it's never been a big deal for me).